# Does IsolatedStorageFileStream.Lock work under SIlverlight4?

Tags: silverlight, locking, silverlight-4.0

Silverlight uses an IsolatedStorageFileStream to open files.

The IsolatedStorageFileStreamunder NET.4 claims to support the [Lock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream_methods%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (Inherited from FileStream)

The following code

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf;
IsolatedStorageFileStream lockStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream( "my.lck", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isf );
lockStream.Lock( 0, 0 );
```

generates the following error, wrapped for readability, under VS2010 and Silverlight 4

```
'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream' does not contain a definition for 'Lock' 
and no extension method 'Lock' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lock` and `Unlock` are not actually supported but are present so that the `System.IO.FileStream` classes are consistent between frameworks and allows for the feature to be implemented in the future.